# Inserting VueJS component template in HTML page not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following main.js:

```
import Test from './components/Test.vue'

Vue.component('test', Test);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.vue-wrap',
    components: { Test },
});
window.vm = vm;
```

And I have the folllowing Test.vue:

```
<template>
    <li>
        Hello World
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Test',
    }
</script>
```

I build the application and I copy the content of "dist" folder in my website's "vue" folder. I have the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=76x76 href=static/img/apple-icon.png><link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=96x96 href=static/img/favicon.png><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><title>My App!</title><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0"><link type=text/css href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300" rel=stylesheet><link type=text/css href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel=stylesheet><link type=text/css href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><link type=text/css href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=static/css/themify-icons.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/vue/static/css/app.d9b210b92ea60ad0856c8dc063cccfec.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div class=wrapper id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/vue/static/js/manifest.bdf9878acc459aaa413c.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/vue/static/js/vendor.0eae82ab4e0e2a32fd9c.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/vue/static/js/app.aa1500d2bdd1b2f93122.js></script>

<div class="vue-wrap">
  <test></test>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vue-paper-dashboard-pro",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "A premium Vue.js admin dashboard for bootstrap. Coded by Cristi Jora, designed by Creative Tim.",
  "author": "cristian.jora <cristian.jora@corebuild.eu>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env ENABLE_ESLINT=false node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "cross-env ENABLE_ESLINT=false node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "unit:watch": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --watch",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "element-ui": "^2.0.3",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.6.2",
    "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jvectormap-next": "^3.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "0.7.1",
    "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.2",
    "router": "^1.3.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^6.11.4",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.21",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-beautify": "^1.1.3",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.7.0",
    "vue-google-autocomplete": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-nav-tabs": "^0.5.4",
    "vue-notifyjs": "^0.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-component": "^0.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^4.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "lolex": "^1.5.2",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Shouldn't VueJs populate the "test" tag directly with HTML? Because in my case all css/js files are loaded ok, if I enter "vm" in console I can see the Vue object, but still, the template part is not inserted in HTML. How can I do that? My page is empty. I want to load multiple components and they should be inserted in the component slots if these are found in HTML.

Comment: don't you have warnings or errors in the browser developers tool?

Comment: How do you "build the application"? Are you using Vue-CLI, and if so, what version?

Comment: sudo npm run build, and I copy-paste the generated files from the "dist" folder to my website's "vue" folder. No errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it as the root component, you can just directly use that component using `render()`

```js
import Test from './components/Test.vue'

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '.vue-wrap',
  render: h => h(Test)
});
```

Comment: Yes, I had to create different variables for each component with the Render option. The render option make the template to appear. That's a must have in my case. Thanks.

Comment: Question: if I have multiple components is it a good practice to render all by default? I want to create a new Vue element for each component that I'm using in a spot.

Comment: No, if you want to use then in multiple places, yhen you need to use ‘Vue.component’. But if you only want to use it few times you may just consider manually adding then to the ‘components’ property inside the component that will use the component.

Comment: if I use Vue.component, how can I render it? Because I tried: Vue.use('test', Test); and it wasn't rendered inside the <test></test> spot. It is only rendered when I use: render: h => h(Test)

Comment: if you use `Vue.component` to register a component, you don't need to add it to the `components` property. In the code you included in your question, you used `Vue.component` and also used added it into the `components` property which is actually very redundant.

Comment: Well.. good point, That was the main issue. Now I don't have to use Render anymore. Many thanks.

Comment: sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add **template** part:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.vue-wrap',
    components: { Test },
    template: '<Test/>
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. But I want to load multiple components, so I have to paste all the slots in the template after <test></test>

Comment: Not working. The index.html file which was described above is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd want to be able to specify components Vue is using by wrapping it in the "main" `<div class="vue-wrap">` you can make use of [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.vue-wrap',
    template: "<slot></slot>",
    components: { 
        /* all components injected by "slots" */ 
        Test, 
        SomeComponent
    },
});
```

... then you can inject your `<test></test>` component by adding it as a child of a main div.

```js
<div class="vue-wrap">
    <test></test>
    <some-component></some-component>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if you're able to write your template inside Vue components, you should use `template` key/option as suggested by @latovic.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.vue-wrap',
    template: `
        <test></test>
        <some-component></some-component>
    `,
    components: { Test, SomeComponent }
});
```

If you're building your application, in other words, if you can use `.vue` files, then you can write template inside your [single-file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

**UPDATE (DUE TO QUESTION UPDATES)**

In your particular example, try removing `Vue.component('test', Tree);` asi it may cause some problems because of case in-sensitive names (this way you're creating global component `test` and you already imported and registered component `Test`).

Also, as mentioned before, if you want to pass `<test></test>` to your HTML and not a template, you'd need a `<slot></slot>`.

```js
import Test from "/path/to/component";

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.vue-wrap',
    template: "<slot></slot>",
    components: { 
        /* all components injected by "slots" */ 
        Test
    },
});
```

But if your index.html is completely empty, it's an issue with your build process, which we cannot help with, as we have no information about it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. But I want to load multiple components, so the second case I guess it won't work unless I paste all the slots in the template after <test></test>.

Comment: Well you can pass as many components and html as you want, the thing is that it needs to be registered in the component your using a slot in, in your case, you can pass more components after `<test></test>`, but you need to add them all to `components` option of the Vue instance. See updated answer.

Comment: Not working. I tried both examples. The index.html file which was described above is empty.

Comment: Well, if it's empty i think it's a question about the build process, not the vue application itself. Can you add the package.json `scripts` part to your question? 
Just so we can see what is ran by `sudo npm run build`.

Comment: I just updated the question and I added the [ackage.json file. I'm using a template called: vue-paper-dashboard-pro . It's a good starter.

Comment: Updated the answer, I'm guessing it must to be a problem with the build, but the files for `vue-paper-dashboard-pro` are not accessible for free and you haven't specified anything about the build process, so it's hard to tell what's going on/

Comment: I had to use the "render" option inside the new Vue(). See Julian's answer. Thanks for your suggestions and your time.